# Integrating AngularJS and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing a Spring based application, with Thymeleaf as the template engine. I am using AngularJS in the html5 pages generated.

Is there a way I can use the JS variables alongwith Thymeleaf?

For instance, consider that my html receives a variable 'id' from my angularJS controller. Assume that Angular sends back the value of id as 1

Using Thymeleaf, I wish to create a link like `<a th:href="/url/{{id}}"></a>`
here, id is the value being passed or generated from Angular.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because thymeleaf is rendered on the server side, and angular on the client side. `th:href` expression need this `id` variable on server.

Comment: I thought so.So can this be possible that if I receive some object from thymeleaf, I can assign it to a variable in my AngularJS controller using inline javascript?

Comment: Give it a try, maybe this will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it this way

```
<a th:href="@{/user/profile/setting/{{currentUser.id}} }">Profile</a>
```